# Getting the City & Country list in iOS Time Zone

Tags: ios, swift, timezone

I want to get access to the user-friendly Time Zone list that appears in the Settings > General > Date & Time. Can someone help in providing the code for this?

[Settings > General > Data & Time > Time Zone (Selection)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBuEH.png)

Comment: I think they provide different answers depending on time of year (DST or NO DST). Not the city list but the contents of each one. There is for example Pacific Daylight Time and Pacific Standard Time.  They change the seconds from GMT to accomplish the time shift.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Swift 4**

Get the current user time zone:

```
let currentTimeZone = TimeZone.current
```

Get all time zones:

```
let timeZoneIdentifiers = TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers
```

Create time zone with identifier:

```
let berlin = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Berlin")!
```

Get city name of time zone:

```
let cityName = berlin.identifier.split(separator: "/").last!
```

Get all city names:

```
    let allCities = timeZoneIdentifiers.compactMap { identifier in
        return identifier.split(separator: "/").last
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Almost there. You must have noticed that in the Time Zone list shown in settings, you have a lot more cities than there are time zones. This is obviously because users would be able to specify their city than a time zone. The code that you provided takes the time zones only and not the complete city list visible in the ios Date & Time settings. Any clue where that is coming from?

Comment: What exactly do you need?
If you need the capital cities of each country you can parse this JSON-Document: https://github.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/blob/master/countriesToCities.json

Comment: Yes, this works fine. I was under the impression that the Time Zone list (shown in settings) was readily available just like the Time Zone identifiers.

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to accept answers that best answer your questions by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I did that just now.

Comment: Time zone identifiers don't account for all major cities so this won't work for most of the major cities in the world. For example, New York (not New York City) is there, but Baltimore and Boston aren't. While this will meet your need to get the identifier list, the above code won't help you if you wanted to translate a city to timezone.

Answer (score 9):

To get the full list:

```
    let knownTimeZoneIdentifiers = TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers
    for tz in TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers {
        let timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: tz)
        if let abbreviation = timeZone?.abbreviation(), let seconds = timeZone?.secondsFromGMT() {
            print ("timeZone: \(tz) \nabbreviation: \(abbreviation)\nsecondsFromGMT: \(seconds)\n")
        }
    }
```

Currently showing this list:

> TZ: Africa/Abidjan  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Africa/Accra  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Africa/Addis_Ababa  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Africa/Algiers  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Africa/Asmara  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Africa/Bamako  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Africa/Bangui  Abbr: GMT+1 SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Africa/Banjul  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Africa/Bissau  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Africa/Blantyre  Abbr: GMT+2 SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Africa/Brazzaville  Abbr: GMT+1 SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Africa/Bujumbura  Abbr: GMT+2 SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Africa/Cairo  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Africa/Casablanca  Abbr: WET SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Africa/Ceuta  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Africa/Conakry  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Africa/Dakar  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Africa/Dar_es_Salaam  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Africa/Djibouti  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Africa/Douala  Abbr: GMT+1 SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Africa/El_Aaiun  Abbr: WET SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Africa/Freetown  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Africa/Gaborone  Abbr: GMT+2 SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Africa/Harare  Abbr: GMT+2 SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Africa/Johannesburg  Abbr: GMT+2 SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Africa/Juba  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Africa/Kampala  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Africa/Khartoum  Abbr: GMT+2 SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Africa/Kigali  Abbr: GMT+2 SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Africa/Kinshasa  Abbr: GMT+1 SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Africa/Lagos  Abbr: GMT+1 SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Africa/Libreville  Abbr: GMT+1 SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Africa/Lome  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Africa/Luanda  Abbr: GMT+1 SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Africa/Lubumbashi  Abbr: GMT+2 SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Africa/Lusaka  Abbr: GMT+2 SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Africa/Malabo  Abbr: GMT+1 SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Africa/Maputo  Abbr: GMT+2 SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Africa/Maseru  Abbr: GMT+2 SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Africa/Mbabane  Abbr: GMT+2 SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Africa/Mogadishu  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Africa/Monrovia  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Africa/Nairobi  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Africa/Ndjamena  Abbr: GMT+1 SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Africa/Niamey  Abbr: GMT+1 SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Africa/Nouakchott  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Africa/Ouagadougou  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Africa/Porto-Novo  Abbr: GMT+1 SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Africa/Sao_Tome  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Africa/Tripoli  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Africa/Tunis  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Africa/Windhoek  Abbr: GMT+2 SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: America/Adak  Abbr: GMT-10 SecondsFromGMT: -36000
>
> TZ: America/Anchorage  Abbr: GMT-9 SecondsFromGMT: -32400
>
> TZ: America/Anguilla  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Antigua  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Araguaina  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Argentina/Catamarca  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Argentina/Cordoba  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Argentina/Jujuy  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Argentina/La_Rioja  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Argentina/Mendoza  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Argentina/Salta  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Argentina/San_Juan  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Argentina/San_Luis  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Argentina/Tucuman  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Argentina/Ushuaia  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Aruba  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Asuncion  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Atikokan  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Bahia  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Bahia_Banderas  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Barbados  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Belem  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Belize  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Blanc-Sablon  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Boa_Vista  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Bogota  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Boise  Abbr: GMT-7 SecondsFromGMT: -25200
>
> TZ: America/Cambridge_Bay  Abbr: GMT-7 SecondsFromGMT: -25200
>
> TZ: America/Campo_Grande  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Cancun  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Caracas  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Cayenne  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Cayman  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Chicago  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Chihuahua  Abbr: GMT-7 SecondsFromGMT: -25200
>
> TZ: America/Costa_Rica  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Creston  Abbr: GMT-7 SecondsFromGMT: -25200
>
> TZ: America/Cuiaba  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Curacao  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Danmarkshavn  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: America/Dawson  Abbr: GMT-8 SecondsFromGMT: -28800
>
> TZ: America/Dawson_Creek  Abbr: GMT-7 SecondsFromGMT: -25200
>
> TZ: America/Denver  Abbr: GMT-7 SecondsFromGMT: -25200
>
> TZ: America/Detroit  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Dominica  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Edmonton  Abbr: GMT-7 SecondsFromGMT: -25200
>
> TZ: America/Eirunepe  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/El_Salvador  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Fort_Nelson  Abbr: GMT-7 SecondsFromGMT: -25200
>
> TZ: America/Fortaleza  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Glace_Bay  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Godthab  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Goose_Bay  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Grand_Turk  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Grenada  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Guadeloupe  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Guatemala  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Guayaquil  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Guyana  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Halifax  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Havana  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Hermosillo  Abbr: GMT-7 SecondsFromGMT: -25200
>
> TZ: America/Indiana/Indianapolis  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Indiana/Knox  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Indiana/Marengo  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Indiana/Petersburg  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Indiana/Tell_City  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Indiana/Vevay  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Indiana/Vincennes  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Indiana/Winamac  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Inuvik  Abbr: GMT-7 SecondsFromGMT: -25200
>
> TZ: America/Iqaluit  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Jamaica  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Juneau  Abbr: GMT-9 SecondsFromGMT: -32400
>
> TZ: America/Kentucky/Louisville  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Kentucky/Monticello  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Kralendijk  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/La_Paz  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Lima  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Los_Angeles  Abbr: GMT-8 SecondsFromGMT: -28800
>
> TZ: America/Lower_Princes  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Maceio  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Managua  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Manaus  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Marigot  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Martinique  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Matamoros  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Mazatlan  Abbr: GMT-7 SecondsFromGMT: -25200
>
> TZ: America/Menominee  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Merida  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Metlakatla  Abbr: GMT-9 SecondsFromGMT: -32400
>
> TZ: America/Mexico_City  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Miquelon  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Moncton  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Monterrey  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Montevideo  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Montreal  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Montserrat  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Nassau  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/New_York  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Nipigon  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Nome  Abbr: GMT-9 SecondsFromGMT: -32400
>
> TZ: America/Noronha  Abbr: GMT-2 SecondsFromGMT: -7200
>
> TZ: America/North_Dakota/Beulah  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/North_Dakota/Center  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/North_Dakota/New_Salem  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Ojinaga  Abbr: GMT-7 SecondsFromGMT: -25200
>
> TZ: America/Panama  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Pangnirtung  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Paramaribo  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Phoenix  Abbr: GMT-7 SecondsFromGMT: -25200
>
> TZ: America/Port-au-Prince  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Port_of_Spain  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Porto_Velho  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Puerto_Rico  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Punta_Arenas  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Rainy_River  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Rankin_Inlet  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Recife  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Regina  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Resolute  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Rio_Branco  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Santa_Isabel  Abbr: GMT-8 SecondsFromGMT: -28800
>
> TZ: America/Santarem  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Santiago  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Santo_Domingo  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Sao_Paulo  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: America/Scoresbysund  Abbr: GMT-1 SecondsFromGMT: -3600
>
> TZ: America/Shiprock  Abbr: GMT-7 SecondsFromGMT: -25200
>
> TZ: America/Sitka  Abbr: GMT-9 SecondsFromGMT: -32400
>
> TZ: America/St_Barthelemy  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/St_Johns  Abbr: GMT-3:30 SecondsFromGMT: -12600
>
> TZ: America/St_Kitts  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/St_Lucia  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/St_Thomas  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/St_Vincent  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Swift_Current  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Tegucigalpa  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Thule  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Thunder_Bay  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Tijuana  Abbr: GMT-8 SecondsFromGMT: -28800
>
> TZ: America/Toronto  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: America/Tortola  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: America/Vancouver  Abbr: GMT-8 SecondsFromGMT: -28800
>
> TZ: America/Whitehorse  Abbr: GMT-8 SecondsFromGMT: -28800
>
> TZ: America/Winnipeg  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: America/Yakutat  Abbr: GMT-9 SecondsFromGMT: -32400
>
> TZ: America/Yellowknife  Abbr: GMT-7 SecondsFromGMT: -25200
>
> TZ: Antarctica/Casey  Abbr: GMT+11 SecondsFromGMT: 39600
>
> TZ: Antarctica/Davis  Abbr: GMT+7 SecondsFromGMT: 25200
>
> TZ: Antarctica/DumontDUrville  Abbr: GMT+10 SecondsFromGMT: 36000
>
> TZ: Antarctica/Macquarie  Abbr: GMT+11 SecondsFromGMT: 39600
>
> TZ: Antarctica/Mawson  Abbr: GMT+5 SecondsFromGMT: 18000
>
> TZ: Antarctica/McMurdo  Abbr: GMT+13 SecondsFromGMT: 46800
>
> TZ: Antarctica/Palmer  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: Antarctica/Rothera  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: Antarctica/South_Pole  Abbr: GMT+13 SecondsFromGMT: 46800
>
> TZ: Antarctica/Syowa  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Antarctica/Troll  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Antarctica/Vostok  Abbr: GMT+6 SecondsFromGMT: 21600
>
> TZ: Arctic/Longyearbyen  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Asia/Aden  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Asia/Almaty  Abbr: GMT+6 SecondsFromGMT: 21600
>
> TZ: Asia/Amman  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Asia/Anadyr  Abbr: GMT+12 SecondsFromGMT: 43200
>
> TZ: Asia/Aqtau  Abbr: GMT+5 SecondsFromGMT: 18000
>
> TZ: Asia/Aqtobe  Abbr: GMT+5 SecondsFromGMT: 18000
>
> TZ: Asia/Ashgabat  Abbr: GMT+5 SecondsFromGMT: 18000
>
> TZ: Asia/Atyrau  Abbr: GMT+5 SecondsFromGMT: 18000
>
> TZ: Asia/Baghdad  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Asia/Bahrain  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Asia/Baku  Abbr: GMT+4 SecondsFromGMT: 14400
>
> TZ: Asia/Bangkok  Abbr: GMT+7 SecondsFromGMT: 25200
>
> TZ: Asia/Barnaul  Abbr: GMT+7 SecondsFromGMT: 25200
>
> TZ: Asia/Beirut  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Asia/Bishkek  Abbr: GMT+6 SecondsFromGMT: 21600
>
> TZ: Asia/Brunei  Abbr: GMT+8 SecondsFromGMT: 28800
>
> TZ: Asia/Calcutta  Abbr: GMT+5:30 SecondsFromGMT: 19800
>
> TZ: Asia/Chita  Abbr: GMT+9 SecondsFromGMT: 32400
>
> TZ: Asia/Choibalsan  Abbr: GMT+8 SecondsFromGMT: 28800
>
> TZ: Asia/Chongqing  Abbr: GMT+8 SecondsFromGMT: 28800
>
> TZ: Asia/Colombo  Abbr: GMT+5:30 SecondsFromGMT: 19800
>
> TZ: Asia/Damascus  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Asia/Dhaka  Abbr: GMT+6 SecondsFromGMT: 21600
>
> TZ: Asia/Dili  Abbr: GMT+9 SecondsFromGMT: 32400
>
> TZ: Asia/Dubai  Abbr: GMT+4 SecondsFromGMT: 14400
>
> TZ: Asia/Dushanbe  Abbr: GMT+5 SecondsFromGMT: 18000
>
> TZ: Asia/Famagusta  Abbr: GMT+2 SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Asia/Gaza  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Asia/Harbin  Abbr: GMT+8 SecondsFromGMT: 28800
>
> TZ: Asia/Hebron  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh  Abbr: GMT+7 SecondsFromGMT: 25200
>
> TZ: Asia/Hong_Kong  Abbr: GMT+8 SecondsFromGMT: 28800
>
> TZ: Asia/Hovd  Abbr: GMT+7 SecondsFromGMT: 25200
>
> TZ: Asia/Irkutsk  Abbr: GMT+8 SecondsFromGMT: 28800
>
> TZ: Asia/Jakarta  Abbr: GMT+7 SecondsFromGMT: 25200
>
> TZ: Asia/Jayapura  Abbr: GMT+9 SecondsFromGMT: 32400
>
> TZ: Asia/Jerusalem  Abbr: GMT+2 SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Asia/Kabul  Abbr: GMT+4:30 SecondsFromGMT: 16200
>
> TZ: Asia/Kamchatka  Abbr: GMT+12 SecondsFromGMT: 43200
>
> TZ: Asia/Karachi  Abbr: GMT+5 SecondsFromGMT: 18000
>
> TZ: Asia/Kashgar  Abbr: GMT+6 SecondsFromGMT: 21600
>
> TZ: Asia/Kathmandu  Abbr: GMT+5:45 SecondsFromGMT: 20700
>
> TZ: Asia/Katmandu  Abbr: GMT+5:45 SecondsFromGMT: 20700
>
> TZ: Asia/Khandyga  Abbr: GMT+9 SecondsFromGMT: 32400
>
> TZ: Asia/Krasnoyarsk  Abbr: GMT+7 SecondsFromGMT: 25200
>
> TZ: Asia/Kuala_Lumpur  Abbr: GMT+8 SecondsFromGMT: 28800
>
> TZ: Asia/Kuching  Abbr: GMT+8 SecondsFromGMT: 28800
>
> TZ: Asia/Kuwait  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Asia/Macau  Abbr: GMT+8 SecondsFromGMT: 28800
>
> TZ: Asia/Magadan  Abbr: GMT+11 SecondsFromGMT: 39600
>
> TZ: Asia/Makassar  Abbr: GMT+8 SecondsFromGMT: 28800
>
> TZ: Asia/Manila  Abbr: GMT+8 SecondsFromGMT: 28800
>
> TZ: Asia/Muscat  Abbr: GMT+4 SecondsFromGMT: 14400
>
> TZ: Asia/Nicosia  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Asia/Novokuznetsk  Abbr: GMT+7 SecondsFromGMT: 25200
>
> TZ: Asia/Novosibirsk  Abbr: GMT+7 SecondsFromGMT: 25200
>
> TZ: Asia/Omsk  Abbr: GMT+6 SecondsFromGMT: 21600
>
> TZ: Asia/Oral  Abbr: GMT+5 SecondsFromGMT: 18000
>
> TZ: Asia/Phnom_Penh  Abbr: GMT+7 SecondsFromGMT: 25200
>
> TZ: Asia/Pontianak  Abbr: GMT+7 SecondsFromGMT: 25200
>
> TZ: Asia/Pyongyang  Abbr: GMT+8:30 SecondsFromGMT: 30600
>
> TZ: Asia/Qatar  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Asia/Qyzylorda  Abbr: GMT+6 SecondsFromGMT: 21600
>
> TZ: Asia/Rangoon  Abbr: GMT+6:30 SecondsFromGMT: 23400
>
> TZ: Asia/Riyadh  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Asia/Sakhalin  Abbr: GMT+11 SecondsFromGMT: 39600
>
> TZ: Asia/Samarkand  Abbr: GMT+5 SecondsFromGMT: 18000
>
> TZ: Asia/Seoul  Abbr: GMT+9 SecondsFromGMT: 32400
>
> TZ: Asia/Shanghai  Abbr: GMT+8 SecondsFromGMT: 28800
>
> TZ: Asia/Singapore  Abbr: GMT+8 SecondsFromGMT: 28800
>
> TZ: Asia/Srednekolymsk  Abbr: GMT+11 SecondsFromGMT: 39600
>
> TZ: Asia/Taipei  Abbr: GMT+8 SecondsFromGMT: 28800
>
> TZ: Asia/Tashkent  Abbr: GMT+5 SecondsFromGMT: 18000
>
> TZ: Asia/Tbilisi  Abbr: GMT+4 SecondsFromGMT: 14400
>
> TZ: Asia/Tehran  Abbr: GMT+3:30 SecondsFromGMT: 12600
>
> TZ: Asia/Thimphu  Abbr: GMT+6 SecondsFromGMT: 21600
>
> TZ: Asia/Tokyo  Abbr: GMT+9 SecondsFromGMT: 32400
>
> TZ: Asia/Tomsk  Abbr: GMT+7 SecondsFromGMT: 25200
>
> TZ: Asia/Ulaanbaatar  Abbr: GMT+8 SecondsFromGMT: 28800
>
> TZ: Asia/Urumqi  Abbr: GMT+6 SecondsFromGMT: 21600
>
> TZ: Asia/Ust-Nera  Abbr: GMT+10 SecondsFromGMT: 36000
>
> TZ: Asia/Vientiane  Abbr: GMT+7 SecondsFromGMT: 25200
>
> TZ: Asia/Vladivostok  Abbr: GMT+10 SecondsFromGMT: 36000
>
> TZ: Asia/Yakutsk  Abbr: GMT+9 SecondsFromGMT: 32400
>
> TZ: Asia/Yangon  Abbr: GMT+6:30 SecondsFromGMT: 23400
>
> TZ: Asia/Yekaterinburg  Abbr: GMT+5 SecondsFromGMT: 18000
>
> TZ: Asia/Yerevan  Abbr: GMT+4 SecondsFromGMT: 14400
>
> TZ: Atlantic/Azores  Abbr: GMT-1 SecondsFromGMT: -3600
>
> TZ: Atlantic/Bermuda  Abbr: GMT-4 SecondsFromGMT: -14400
>
> TZ: Atlantic/Canary  Abbr: WET SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Atlantic/Cape_Verde  Abbr: GMT-1 SecondsFromGMT: -3600
>
> TZ: Atlantic/Faroe  Abbr: WET SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Atlantic/Madeira  Abbr: WET SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Atlantic/Reykjavik  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Atlantic/South_Georgia  Abbr: GMT-2 SecondsFromGMT: -7200
>
> TZ: Atlantic/St_Helena  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Atlantic/Stanley  Abbr: GMT-3 SecondsFromGMT: -10800
>
> TZ: Australia/Adelaide  Abbr: GMT+10:30 SecondsFromGMT: 37800
>
> TZ: Australia/Brisbane  Abbr: GMT+10 SecondsFromGMT: 36000
>
> TZ: Australia/Broken_Hill  Abbr: GMT+10:30 SecondsFromGMT: 37800
>
> TZ: Australia/Currie  Abbr: GMT+11 SecondsFromGMT: 39600
>
> TZ: Australia/Darwin  Abbr: GMT+9:30 SecondsFromGMT: 34200
>
> TZ: Australia/Eucla  Abbr: GMT+8:45 SecondsFromGMT: 31500
>
> TZ: Australia/Hobart  Abbr: GMT+11 SecondsFromGMT: 39600
>
> TZ: Australia/Lindeman  Abbr: GMT+10 SecondsFromGMT: 36000
>
> TZ: Australia/Lord_Howe  Abbr: GMT+11 SecondsFromGMT: 39600
>
> TZ: Australia/Melbourne  Abbr: GMT+11 SecondsFromGMT: 39600
>
> TZ: Australia/Perth  Abbr: GMT+8 SecondsFromGMT: 28800
>
> TZ: Australia/Sydney  Abbr: GMT+11 SecondsFromGMT: 39600
>
> TZ: Europe/Amsterdam  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Andorra  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Astrakhan  Abbr: GMT+4 SecondsFromGMT: 14400
>
> TZ: Europe/Athens  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Europe/Belgrade  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Berlin  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Bratislava  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Brussels  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Bucharest  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Europe/Budapest  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Busingen  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Chisinau  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Europe/Copenhagen  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Dublin  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Europe/Gibraltar  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Guernsey  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Europe/Helsinki  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Europe/Isle_of_Man  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Europe/Istanbul  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Europe/Jersey  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Europe/Kaliningrad  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Europe/Kiev  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Europe/Kirov  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Europe/Lisbon  Abbr: WET SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Europe/Ljubljana  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/London  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Europe/Luxembourg  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Madrid  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Malta  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Mariehamn  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Europe/Minsk  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Europe/Monaco  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Moscow  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Europe/Oslo  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Paris  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Podgorica  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Prague  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Riga  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Europe/Rome  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Samara  Abbr: GMT+4 SecondsFromGMT: 14400
>
> TZ: Europe/San_Marino  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Sarajevo  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Saratov  Abbr: GMT+4 SecondsFromGMT: 14400
>
> TZ: Europe/Simferopol  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Europe/Skopje  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Sofia  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Europe/Stockholm  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Tallinn  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Europe/Tirane  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Ulyanovsk  Abbr: GMT+4 SecondsFromGMT: 14400
>
> TZ: Europe/Uzhgorod  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Europe/Vaduz  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Vatican  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Vienna  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Vilnius  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Europe/Volgograd  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Europe/Warsaw  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Zagreb  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: Europe/Zaporozhye  Abbr: EET SecondsFromGMT: 7200
>
> TZ: Europe/Zurich  Abbr: CET SecondsFromGMT: 3600
>
> TZ: GMT  Abbr: GMT SecondsFromGMT: 0
>
> TZ: Indian/Antananarivo  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Indian/Chagos  Abbr: GMT+6 SecondsFromGMT: 21600
>
> TZ: Indian/Christmas  Abbr: GMT+7 SecondsFromGMT: 25200
>
> TZ: Indian/Cocos  Abbr: GMT+6:30 SecondsFromGMT: 23400
>
> TZ: Indian/Comoro  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Indian/Kerguelen  Abbr: GMT+5 SecondsFromGMT: 18000
>
> TZ: Indian/Mahe  Abbr: GMT+4 SecondsFromGMT: 14400
>
> TZ: Indian/Maldives  Abbr: GMT+5 SecondsFromGMT: 18000
>
> TZ: Indian/Mauritius  Abbr: GMT+4 SecondsFromGMT: 14400
>
> TZ: Indian/Mayotte  Abbr: GMT+3 SecondsFromGMT: 10800
>
> TZ: Indian/Reunion  Abbr: GMT+4 SecondsFromGMT: 14400
>
> TZ: Pacific/Apia  Abbr: GMT+14 SecondsFromGMT: 50400
>
> TZ: Pacific/Auckland  Abbr: GMT+13 SecondsFromGMT: 46800
>
> TZ: Pacific/Bougainville  Abbr: GMT+11 SecondsFromGMT: 39600
>
> TZ: Pacific/Chatham  Abbr: GMT+13:45 SecondsFromGMT: 49500
>
> TZ: Pacific/Chuuk  Abbr: GMT+10 SecondsFromGMT: 36000
>
> TZ: Pacific/Easter  Abbr: GMT-5 SecondsFromGMT: -18000
>
> TZ: Pacific/Efate  Abbr: GMT+11 SecondsFromGMT: 39600
>
> TZ: Pacific/Enderbury  Abbr: GMT+13 SecondsFromGMT: 46800
>
> TZ: Pacific/Fakaofo  Abbr: GMT+13 SecondsFromGMT: 46800
>
> TZ: Pacific/Fiji  Abbr: GMT+12 SecondsFromGMT: 43200
>
> TZ: Pacific/Funafuti  Abbr: GMT+12 SecondsFromGMT: 43200
>
> TZ: Pacific/Galapagos  Abbr: GMT-6 SecondsFromGMT: -21600
>
> TZ: Pacific/Gambier  Abbr: GMT-9 SecondsFromGMT: -32400
>
> TZ: Pacific/Guadalcanal  Abbr: GMT+11 SecondsFromGMT: 39600
>
> TZ: Pacific/Guam  Abbr: GMT+10 SecondsFromGMT: 36000
>
> TZ: Pacific/Honolulu  Abbr: GMT-10 SecondsFromGMT: -36000
>
> TZ: Pacific/Johnston  Abbr: GMT-10 SecondsFromGMT: -36000
>
> TZ: Pacific/Kiritimati  Abbr: GMT+14 SecondsFromGMT: 50400
>
> TZ: Pacific/Kosrae  Abbr: GMT+11 SecondsFromGMT: 39600
>
> TZ: Pacific/Kwajalein  Abbr: GMT+12 SecondsFromGMT: 43200
>
> TZ: Pacific/Majuro  Abbr: GMT+12 SecondsFromGMT: 43200
>
> TZ: Pacific/Marquesas  Abbr: GMT-9:30 SecondsFromGMT: -34200
>
> TZ: Pacific/Midway  Abbr: GMT-11 SecondsFromGMT: -39600
>
> TZ: Pacific/Nauru  Abbr: GMT+12 SecondsFromGMT: 43200
>
> TZ: Pacific/Niue  Abbr: GMT-11 SecondsFromGMT: -39600
>
> TZ: Pacific/Norfolk  Abbr: GMT+11 SecondsFromGMT: 39600
>
> TZ: Pacific/Noumea  Abbr: GMT+11 SecondsFromGMT: 39600
>
> TZ: Pacific/Pago_Pago  Abbr: GMT-11 SecondsFromGMT: -39600
>
> TZ: Pacific/Palau  Abbr: GMT+9 SecondsFromGMT: 32400
>
> TZ: Pacific/Pitcairn  Abbr: GMT-8 SecondsFromGMT: -28800
>
> TZ: Pacific/Pohnpei  Abbr: GMT+11 SecondsFromGMT: 39600
>
> TZ: Pacific/Ponape  Abbr: GMT+11 SecondsFromGMT: 39600
>
> TZ: Pacific/Port_Moresby  Abbr: GMT+10 SecondsFromGMT: 36000
>
> TZ: Pacific/Rarotonga  Abbr: GMT-10 SecondsFromGMT: -36000
>
> TZ: Pacific/Saipan  Abbr: GMT+10 SecondsFromGMT: 36000
>
> TZ: Pacific/Tahiti  Abbr: GMT-10 SecondsFromGMT: -36000
>
> TZ: Pacific/Tarawa  Abbr: GMT+12 SecondsFromGMT: 43200
>
> TZ: Pacific/Tongatapu  Abbr: GMT+13 SecondsFromGMT: 46800
>
> TZ: Pacific/Truk  Abbr: GMT+10 SecondsFromGMT: 36000
>
> TZ: Pacific/Wake  Abbr: GMT+12 SecondsFromGMT: 43200
>
> TZ: Pacific/Wallis Abbr: GMT+12 SecondsFromGMT: 43200

Comment: It's worth noting that since this question was answered, for whatever reason, the number of abbreviations the system returns has reduced to only African & American timezones. For example, Paris now returns `GMT+2` instead of `CEST`

Answer (score 4):

```
ADT = "America/Halifax";
AKDT = "America/Juneau";
AKST = "America/Juneau";
ART = "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires";
AST = "America/Halifax";
BDT = "Asia/Dhaka";
BRST = "America/Sao_Paulo";
BRT = "America/Sao_Paulo";
BST = "Europe/London";
CAT = "Africa/Harare";
CDT = "America/Chicago";
CEST = "Europe/Paris";
CET = "Europe/Paris";
CLST = "America/Santiago";
CLT = "America/Santiago";
COT = "America/Bogota";
CST = "America/Chicago";
EAT = "Africa/Addis_Ababa";
EDT = "America/New_York";
EEST = "Europe/Istanbul";
EET = "Europe/Istanbul";
EST = "America/New_York";
GMT = GMT;
GST = "Asia/Dubai";
HKT = "Asia/Hong_Kong";
HST = "Pacific/Honolulu";
ICT = "Asia/Bangkok";
IRST = "Asia/Tehran";
IST = "Asia/Calcutta";
JST = "Asia/Tokyo";
KST = "Asia/Seoul";
MDT = "America/Denver";
MSD = "Europe/Moscow";
MSK = "Europe/Moscow";
MST = "America/Denver";
NZDT = "Pacific/Auckland";
NZST = "Pacific/Auckland";
PDT = "America/Los_Angeles";
PET = "America/Lima";
PHT = "Asia/Manila";
PKT = "Asia/Karachi";
PST = "America/Los_Angeles";
SGT = "Asia/Singapore";
UTC = UTC;
WAT = "Africa/Lagos";
WEST = "Europe/Lisbon";
WET = "Europe/Lisbon";
WIT = "Asia/Jakarta";
```

Comment: Good to know how they looks like

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let timezone = TimeZone.current.identifier
```

This will return "America/Sao_Paulo".

Sorry, this will get all list:

```
let array = TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers
```

Comment: Yes, that does do that. But what I am asking is how to get the complete user-friendly list such as "Philadelphia, U.S.A.", "Green Bay, U.S.A.", etc. (in the screenshot of the original post).

Comment: `TimeZone.current.identifier` doesn't return data in `"America/Sao_Paulo"` format anymore...