# Get Time zone id from city and country in android

Tags: android, timezone

Is it possible to get the time zone by country name and city name in android ?

ex : input -> city: Delhi ,country:India

TZ: Asia/Calcutta

i am not able to find good answer for this .

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49048447/4466607)
here is the list of time zone available .

is there any public api for this ?

Comment: Have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406011/location-based-timezone-retrieval

Comment: follow this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates